# Android Socket High CPU usage

Tags: android, sockets, networking, client, cpu-usage

I did a client/server(*android/pc*) and it seems that network usage from client uses a lot of CPU. Like to receive only 4k-5k from network, the cpu rises to 33 milliseconds. The cpu can be higher than 90-100 milliseconds if data is higher like ~32k.

First, I've tried the client(*network part*) in java version and after in c and the problem is still there.

I profiled the server part that send data and it uses about 0 millisecond.

Some details:

- TCP connection.
- The client connects to the server, client sends request, server sends
  data (chunk of 4-10k), client send request, server sends...
- Network part is threaded.
- Get data with (recv or recv/select).
- Smart Phone: Nexus one.
- Tested in profiler mode (only network part and display fps/milliseconds).
- Tested in Wifi (computer, phone, network are close).

Let me know if you have any suggestions or questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using BufferedOutputStream on Android side to write the data? If not, it writes it byte by byte, which would explain the high CPU usage.

If this is not the case, please add some source code to the question.

Comment: For reading/writing, I used a byte[] buffer.

Init:
m_recvBuffer = new byte[RECV_BUFFER_SIZE];

Loop:
socket.getInputStream().read(m_recvBuffer, 0, RECV_BUFFER_SIZE);

And RECV_BUFFER_SIZE is 32768 bytes.

Comment: Try BufferedInputStream around the socket input stream.

Comment: @kichik Why? It won't make any difference.

Comment: @Xunil you should edit your question to include the code you have put in you comment and use the code formatting tools to make it more accessible